# Finding Product in Kitchen that is going to expire soon

Tags: java

What I have so far:

```
class abstract Product {

    public int daysTillExpiration;

    public int dateofManufacture ;

    public Product ( int daysTillExpiration, int dateofManufacture ) {
      this.daysTillExpiration = daysTillExpiration;
      this.dateofManufacture = dateofManufacture;
    }

    int getDaysTillExpiration(){
      return daysTillExpiration;
    }

    int getDateofManufacture() {
      return dateofManufacture;
    }
}
```

And the class **Kitchen**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Kitchen {

  ArrayList<Product> contents = new ArrayList<>();

  ArrayList<Product> getcontents ()
  {
    return contents;
  }
}
```

I created classes of the Products(eggs, wine and cheese) and extends class Product.

What i need do;

I have a `Kitchen` and each `Product` in my `Kitchen` has an expiring date,

This is with `x` days to initialize after creation

```
 x =  for wine 3 years
      for cheese 10 days 
      for eggs 2 days
```

The inquiry should be from the `Kitchen` - which product in the kitchen expires first?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: The constructor of `Product`  does  not match being `Produkte` change to `public Product( int daysTillExpiration, int dateofManufacture ) {` you will want to change `int dateofManufacture` to `Date dateofManufacture`

Comment: Oh Yes, that was a typo. Just did. Thanks for the observation.  And what's the next step from me.

Comment: Does what you have so far compile? Perhaps start there.

Comment: @EvanKnowles I'm sorry but i didn't get you.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your code, as it exists? Getting your code working in small increments helps.

Comment: @EvanKnowles not sure i know what you mean i should do. But no have not tried compiling my code as it exists yet.

Comment: Seems like you already have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774283/can-someone-help-me-with-this-exercise

Comment: @SteffenKreutz Yes I know but not total elaborated like i would have understood.

Comment: @KennethClark In the classes of the products do i put the daysTillExpiration  and  dateofManufacture like how? after  extends construction has been added

Comment: @ThomasKlapp take a look at the answer that may help you

Comment: @KennethClark Thanks so much for that answer. I will study it and implement it my way. I really hope it helps.

Comment: @KennethClark Can't thank you enough. Hope you would be willing to assistance again if i need an helping hand? Sorry I took much of your time. Thanks a million. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Product class which looks like

```
 public class Product
  {
    private Date purchaseDate = null;
    private int daysTillExpiry = 0;
    private Date expiryDate = null;
    private String productDescription = null;

    public Product(Date purchaseDate, int daysTillExpiry, String productDescription)
    {
      this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
      this.daysTillExpiry = daysTillExpiry;
      this.productDescription = productDescription;

      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTime(purchaseDate);
      calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, daysTillExpiry);
      expiryDate = calendar.getTime();
    }

    public Date getPurchaseDate()
    {
      return purchaseDate;
    }

    public int getDaysTillExpiry()
    {
      return daysTillExpiry;
    }

    public Date getExpiryDate()
    {
      return expiryDate;
    }

    public String getProductDescription()
    {
      return productDescription;
    }
  }
```

and a Kitchen class like

```
  public class Kitchen
  {
    private List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();


    public List<Product> getProductList()
    {
      return productList;
    }
  }
```

Then it will be simply using a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

I have created a test class below which implements a `Comparator` in `printList()` method

```
public class ProductsExpire
{
  private Kitchen kitchen = new Kitchen();


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ProductsExpire productsExpire = new ProductsExpire();
    productsExpire.addProduct(new Date() ,1095,"wine");
    productsExpire.addProduct(new Date() ,10,"cheese");
    productsExpire.addProduct(new Date() ,3,"eggs");
    productsExpire.printList();
  }


  public void addProduct(Date purchaseDate, int daysTillExpiry, String productDescription)
  {
    kitchen.getProductList().add(new Product(purchaseDate, daysTillExpiry, productDescription));
  }

  public void printList()
  {
    Collections.sort(kitchen.getProductList(), new Comparator<Product>()
    {
      @Override
      public int compare(Product leftProduct, Product rightProduct)
      {
        return leftProduct.getExpiryDate().compareTo(rightProduct.getExpiryDate());
      }
    });

    for (Product product : kitchen.getProductList())
    {
      System.out.println(product.getProductDescription() + " " + product.getExpiryDate());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Kitchen myKitchen = new Kitchen();

        myKitchen.addProduct(new Wine("Red Wine", 20150611));
        myKitchen.addProduct(new Cheese("White Cheese", 20150611));
        myKitchen.addProduct(new Wine("White Wine", 20150611));
        myKitchen.addProduct(new Egg("Big Egg", 20150611));

        Product p = myKitchen.getEarliestExpiringProduct();
        System.out.println("Name: " + p.getName() +
                ", Days Left: " + p.getDaysTillExpiration());
    }
}

abstract class Product {

    private String name;
    private int daysTillExpiration;
    private int dateOfManufacture;

    public Product(String name, int daysTillExpiration,
            int dateOfManufacture) {
        this.name = name;
        this.daysTillExpiration = daysTillExpiration;
        this.dateOfManufacture = dateOfManufacture;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getDaysTillExpiration() { return daysTillExpiration; }
    public int getDateofManufacture() { return dateOfManufacture; }
}

class Wine extends Product {

    public Wine(String name, int dateOfManufacture) {
        super(name, 3 * 365, dateOfManufacture);
    }
}

class Cheese extends Product {

    public Cheese(String name, int dateOfManufacture) {
        super(name, 10, dateOfManufacture);
    }
}

class Egg extends Product {

    public Egg(String name, int dateOfManufacture) {
        super(name, 2, dateOfManufacture);
    }
}

class Kitchen {

    ArrayList<Product> contents = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Product> getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product newProduct) {
        contents.add(newProduct);
    }

    public void removeProduct(Product p) {
        contents.remove(p);
    }

    public void sortByDaysLeft() {
        Collections.sort(contents, new Comparator<Product>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
                return ((Integer)p1.getDaysTillExpiration()).compareTo(
                        p2.getDaysTillExpiration());
            }
        });
    }

    public Product getEarliestExpiringProduct() {
        sortByDaysLeft();
        return contents.get(0);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name: Big Egg, Days Left: 2
```

Here is a working version, try to figure out how it works (and stop reposting the same question).
In particular `Comparator<Product>`, which will help you 'sort your Kitchen' and return you
the product that is going to expire soon. For more on [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

**Note:** This is not using the `dateOfManufacture`.
If you intend to use `dateOfManufacture`, it should be declared as a Date and not an int.

Comment: thanks a bunch. I will study this as best as i can to understand how you implemented it so as to make use of it in the future.

Comment: I hope sometime again you can give me an helping hand when i need one.

Comment: @EvanKnowles Yes, I tried to do that but the site said i need 15 reputation to do it. Gosu gave me the very right answer to what i needed.